# Cross browser CSS3 transition jQuery function with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

Why wont this work? It only works on chrome when I remove all vendors and keep webkit, I already did a similar example with 'transform' property with the same method and it's working properly. Thanks

```
function transition(handle,prop,dur,ease){

    handle.css({
        '-webkit-transition': '-webkit-' + prop + ' ' + dur + 'ms ' + ease + '',
        '-moz-transition': '-moz-' + prop + ' ' + dur + 'ms ' + ease  + '',
        '-ms-transition': '-ms-' + prop + ' ' + dur + 'ms ' + ease  + '',
        '-o-transition': '-o-' + prop + ' ' + dur + 'ms ' + ease  + '',
        'transition': prop + ' ' + dur + 'ms ' + ease  + ''
    });
}
```

Comment: what parameters you have passed here..?

Comment: its working : http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/ZAM2h/

Comment: @aslan but it is not working with transform?

Comment: @SoundarR the element, the property, the duration, ease

Comment: @aslan it worked when I removed the last line, why could that cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try like [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAM2h/1/) .. It might works.. The problem may due to, the browser ignore the CSS style when the unknown styles are applied..

**Script:**

```
function transition(handle, prop, dur, ease) {
    handle.css({ '-webkit-transition': '-webkit-' + prop + ' ' + dur + 'ms ' + ease });
    handle.css({ '-moz-transition': '-moz-' + prop + ' ' + dur + 'ms ' + ease });
    handle.css({ '-ms-transition': '-ms-' + prop + ' ' + dur + 'ms ' + ease });
    handle.css({ '-o-transition': '-o-' + prop + ' ' + dur + 'ms ' + ease });
    handle.css({ 'transition': prop + ' ' + dur + 'ms ' + ease });
}
```

Comment: which browser you have used..? The above is worked for me in Chrome without removing that line..

Comment: chrome, but I am using it in a big plugin so there maybe another bug in the code.